# Concrete text font not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu

I installed the following Ubuntu packages on Ubuntu 18.04:

- texlive
- texlive-bibtex-extra
- texlive-fonts-extra
- texlive-generic-recommended
- texlive-lang-german
- texlive-latex-extra
- texlive-xetex

In my preamble, I include the `beton` package (with T1 font encoding). Still, LaTeX complains:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ccr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 28.
```

And indeed, there is no occurrence of `T1/ccr/m/n` anywhere in `/usr/share/texlive`.

So, how do I use the Concrete font on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: you are probably missing t1ccr.fd, on my system it is in the ccfonts package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer, I looked for the ccfonts package in Ubuntu.  This *used* to be in the Ubuntu package `texlive-math-extra` but is now in the new package `texlive-science`.  So, the solution was

```
apt-get install -y texlive-science
```

Comment: It is, BTW, a pain that I have to install `texlive-science` just for the ccfonts, which depends on `texlive-lang-greek`, which is 70 MByte in size!

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the Debian/Ubuntu package that contains a given file with `apt-file`.  For example,

```
apt-file find "t1qpl.fd"
```

returns

```
tex-gyre: /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ot1qpl.fd
tex-gyre: /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tex-gyre/t1qpl.fd
```

If you’re not sure about the exact filename, you can do a full-text keyword search with `apt search`, or a regular expression search for filenames with `apt-file find --regex`.  For example, `apt search Pagella` points me to `fonts-texgyre`, which contains the OpenType version of TeX Gyre Pagella, and `apt-file find --regexp "[pP]agella.*\.otf"` finds three packages that install different versions of it.

You can also search your distro’s package repository online, in case you need to install a package for a different OS version.

If there is no apt/rpm, you can also do a filename search on [CTAN](https://ctan.org), to find a TeX Live package you can install to your local tree.

If all else fails, you can download the files you need to a directory where your utilities can find it, such as: the directory for your project, `~/.texmf` or `$TEXMFHOME`, or for TTF and OTF files, `~/.fonts/` or `/usr/local/share/fonts/`.  It’s a good idea to put them together in a subdirectory, since your computer is not keeping track of where each file is from, new versions, or conflicts.